# How do I use the php date function to determine what is displayed?

Tags: php, html, web

I'm working on a simple site that uses the date function in php to display the current date.  I'm familiar with HTML, CSS, and Java.  Depending on the current date, I want different information to show, such as...

```
On <?php echo date('F jS'); ?> throughout history, the following events took place:
Event 1 in 1776
Event 2 in 1890
Event 3 in 1999
```

I have a list of info, I'm just not sure how to link the 2 together.  Take a look at http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history for a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems to me you'd want a database of events and you'd want to query that?

Comment: @therefromhere would i need to create a sepereate mysql entry for each day, or could i put everything into 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make a table named **events**
2. In **events**, create rows === id, monthandday, year, event
3. Make PHP select:

   ```
   //connect to db
   $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

   //get day and month
   $curdate = date("m d");

   //select from database of events where matching month and day     
   $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE monthandday = :md ");

   $statement->execute(array(':md' => $curdate));

   //echo out events that happened throughout history
   echo "On ."date('F jS') ."throughout history, the following events took place:";

   while($row = $statement->fetch()){

       echo $row['event'];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to format a date in php use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

To get the year

echo date("Y", $date);

Comment: I already know how to get the current date.  I'm looking to connect the current date with a database.